# CSS, cambiar el color de texto que uno escribe

Tags: color, texto

Tengo un problema. En mi página puse un fondo negro. A la hora escribir, por ejemplo, en un `input` el texto que estoy escribiendo también sale en negro y no se puede ver lo que escribo.

¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar el color de texto del que uno escribe?

Sé cambiar el texto que se imprime en pantalla, pero no el texto que uno va escribiendo antes de enviar.

Answer (score 1):

Con la propiedad `color` del `input` puedes cambiarle el color, por ejemplo:

```css
#input{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Escrito también en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/arnolasco/pen/xxgMxpJ):

Comment: Sería bueno que pongas un ejemplo para que se pueda validar como respuesta

Comment: ¿El enlace al codepen con el ejemplo no cuenta?

Comment: Hola, Alfonso. Lamentablemente, no. La razón es porque si deja de estar disponible el recurso ubicado en esa ruta dejará de ser válida la respuesta en esta publicación. De todas maneras, aprobé la edición. Allí puedes observar cómo se agrega un **Snippet** que es lo que te permite correr el código en esta publicación.